# Autologin & VNCSERVER issues

Tags: raspbian, vnc, user

Sorry for the poor title but I couldn't find a better one for my issue as I don't know what's going on.

Recently I write (for purpose that are not relevant now) a fresh Raspbian image from November 2016, I connected the HDMI cable to my monitor and installed [tightvncserver](http://www.tightvnc.com/) and started a normal session with

```
sudo vncserver :1 -geometry xxxXyyy
```

Once I disconnected the HDMI cable and accessed via vnc viewer I noticed an popup error that says:

"no session for pid xxx" where xxx is a pid number, clicked ok and then tried to run the web browser. Once I clicked on the icon nothing happened... no browser launched, the same happened for some other application. When I launched the terminal I noticed that if I set via raspi-config to log in straight into CLI with standard user pid, the terminal session is not logged in as "Pi" but as root. I don't know what is going on... any ideas? I couldn't find any solutions by googling around, can anyone help me out?

**EDIT :** I noticed the if I access CLI directly via cable all of this problem are not showing and everithing mentioned above works just fine

Comment: "can anyone help me" **No** because you have posted a lot of vague waffle with no facts about what you have **actually** done.

Comment: @Milliways I described the problems, and i specified that I don't know exactly what is going on, so I posted what I noticed..